# Image is not Sliding

Tags: jquery, html

i have a parent div in which i have 3 child div's each containing an image 
here is html code

```
<div class="container" >
<div style="display: inline-block; ">
<img src="../Images/t-shirt1.jpg"/>
</div>
<div >
<img src="../Images/ata1.jpg"/>
</div>
<div>
<img src="../Images/ata3.jpg"/>
</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that my currentIndex is not increasing 
and i think that' why my images are not sliding 
here is my jQuery Code

```
 var currentIndex = 0;
      items = $('.container div');
      console.log("Recieved images"+items);
      itemAmt = items.length;
      console.log("Calculate"+itemAmt);
    function cycleItems() {
      var item = $('.container div').eq(currentIndex);
      console.log("next item");
      items.hide();
      console.log("next");
      item.css('display','inline-block');
    }

    var autoSlide = setInterval(function() {
      currentIndex += 1;
      console.log("Interval start"+currentIndex);
      if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
        currentIndex = 0;
      }
      cycleItems();
    }, 3000);

    $('.next').click(function() {
      cleaInterval(autoSlide);
      currentIndex += 1;
      console.log("Interval start");
      if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
        currentIndex = 0;
        console.log("Interval start loop");
      }
      cycleItems();
    });

    $('.prev').click(function() {
      clearInterval(autoSlide);
      currentIndex -= 1;
      if (currentIndex < 0) {
        currentIndex = itemAmt - 1;
      }
      cycleItems();
    });
```

Comment: creating a working model.

Comment: your code works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/xphjhk85/

Answer (score 0):

did you include the jQuery library? This example is working.

```js
 var currentIndex = 0;
      items = $('.container div');
      console.log("Recieved images"+items);
      itemAmt = items.length;
      console.log("Calculate"+itemAmt);
    function cycleItems() {
      var item = $('.container div').eq(currentIndex);
      console.log("next item");
      items.hide();
      console.log("next");
      item.css('display','inline-block');
    }

    var autoSlide = setInterval(function() {
      currentIndex += 1;
      console.log("Interval start"+currentIndex);
      if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
        currentIndex = 0;
      }
      cycleItems();
    }, 3000);

    $('.next').click(function() {
      cleaInterval(autoSlide);
      currentIndex += 1;
      console.log("Interval start");
      if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
        currentIndex = 0;
        console.log("Interval start loop");
      }
      cycleItems();
    });

    $('.prev').click(function() {
      clearInterval(autoSlide);
      currentIndex -= 1;
      if (currentIndex < 0) {
        currentIndex = itemAmt - 1;
      }
      cycleItems();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" >
<div style="display: inline-block; ">
<img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-ApZE8ishxuw/UFBBZzroNfI/AAAAAAAACDo/7g_sZhGk93A/s1600/stock+photos+free+commercial+use.jpg"/>
</div>
<div >
<img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-SAA6zUJiKNM/UFBBa2LXFqI/AAAAAAAACDs/GawDQtdj3XM/s1600/stock+photos+free+people.jpg"/>
</div>
<div>
<img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-vhFl4oghn_U/UFBBcCaF_EI/AAAAAAAACDw/UlHh4QinHLM/s1600/stock+photos+free+trial.jpg"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what is the difference between the example in the code snippet and your code?

Answer (score 0):

While your code is working fine for me .. I think your problem is after you click prev or next buttons you clear a `setInterval()` part and you need to return it back again .. If I guessed well and this is your problem .. you just need to create a function for the `setInterval()` part

```
// ceate a function for setInterval
    var autoSlide;
    function slideImges(){
        autoSlide = setInterval(function() {
        currentIndex += 1;
        console.log("Interval start"+currentIndex);
        if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
          currentIndex = 0;
        }
        cycleItems();
      }, 3000);
    }
```

and in `$('.next')` click event you forgot r in `cleaInterval(autoSlide);` it should be `clearInterval(autoSlide);`

**Here's a Demo**

```js
var currentIndex = 0;
      items = $('.container div');
      console.log("Recieved images"+items);
      itemAmt = items.length;
      console.log("Calculate"+itemAmt);
    function cycleItems() {
      var item = $('.container div').eq(currentIndex);
      console.log("next item");
      items.hide(0);
      console.log("next");
      item.show(0);
    }
    
    // ceate a function for setInterval
  var autoSlide;
    function slideImges(){
       autoSlide = setInterval(function() {
        currentIndex += 1;
        console.log("Interval start"+currentIndex);
        if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
          currentIndex = 0;
        }
        cycleItems();
      }, 3000);
    }
    
    // Call setInterval function here
    slideImges();
    
    $('.next').click(function() {
      clearInterval(autoSlide);
      currentIndex += 1;
      console.log("Interval start");
      if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
        currentIndex = 0;
        console.log("Interval start loop");
      }
      cycleItems();
      // Call setInterval function here
     slideImges();
    });

    $('.prev').click(function() {
      clearInterval(autoSlide);
      currentIndex -= 1;
      if (currentIndex < 0) {
        currentIndex = itemAmt - 1;
      }
      cycleItems();
      // Call setInterval function here
     slideImges();
    });
```

```css
.container div:not(:first-child){
  display : none;
}
.container div img{
  height : 150px;
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" >
  <div style="display: inline-block; ">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
  </div>
  <div >
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100"/>
  </div>
  <div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
  </div>
  <div >
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100"/>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="prev">Prev</button>
<button class="next">Next</button>
```